# Datetime issues while time series predicting in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

Trying to implement the model of time series predicting in python but facing with issues with datetime data.

So I have a dataframe 'df' with two columns of datetime and float types:

[image]

Then I try to build an array using values method. But smth strange happens and it displays the date in strange format with timestamps and time:

[image]

And basically because of it, I can not implement the model receiving the following messages for example:"Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without freq."

So what seems to be the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: Real data please.  Pictures don't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complicated.

First of all, when creating a `numpy` array, all types will be the same.  However, `datetime64` is not the same as `int`.  So we'll have to resolve that, and we will.

Second, you tried to do this with `df.values`.  Which makes sense, however, what happens is that `pandas` makes the whole `df` into `dtype=object` then into an `object` array.  The problem with that is that `Timestamps` get left as `Timestamps` which is getting in your way.

So I'd convert them on my own like this

```
a = np.column_stack([df[c].values.astype(int) for c in ['transaction_date', 'amount']])

a

array([[1454284800000000000,                   1],
       [1454371200000000000,                   2],
       [1454457600000000000,                   3],
       [1454544000000000000,                   4],
       [1454630400000000000,                   5]])
```

We can always convert the first column of a back like this

```
a[:, 0].astype(df.transaction_date.values.dtype)

array(['2016-02-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2016-02-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2016-02-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2016-02-04T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2016-02-05T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your integer into a `timedelta`, and do the calculations as you did before:

```
from datetime import timedelta

interval = timedelta(days = 5)

#5 days later
time_stamp += interval
```