# 'Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without freq' error for ARIMA model although re-indexed with frequency

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, arima

I'm trying to do a time series prediction using an ARIMA model on this series:

```
1960-01-01    12.7
1961-01-01    12.1
1962-01-01    12.7
1963-01-01    12.8
1964-01-01    12.3
1965-01-01    13.0
1966-01-01    12.5
1967-01-01    12.9
1968-01-01    12.9
1969-01-01    13.3
1970-01-01    13.2
1971-01-01    13.0
1972-01-01    12.6
1973-01-01    12.2
1974-01-01    12.4
1975-01-01    12.7
1976-01-01    12.6
1977-01-01    12.2
1978-01-01    12.5
1979-01-01    12.2
1980-01-01    12.2
1981-01-01    12.2
1982-01-01    12.1
1983-01-01    12.3
1984-01-01    11.7
1985-01-01    11.8
1986-01-01    11.5
1987-01-01    11.2
1988-01-01    11.0
1989-01-01    10.9
1990-01-01    10.8
1991-01-01    10.8
1992-01-01    10.6
1993-01-01    10.4
1994-01-01    10.2
1995-01-01    10.2
1996-01-01    10.2
1997-01-01    10.0
1998-01-01     9.8
1999-01-01     9.8
2000-01-01     9.6
2001-01-01     9.3
2002-01-01     9.4
2003-01-01     9.5
2004-01-01     9.1
2005-01-01     9.1
2006-01-01     9.0
2007-01-01     9.0
2008-01-01     9.0
2009-01-01     9.3
2010-01-01     9.2
2011-01-01     9.1
2012-01-01     9.4
2013-01-01     9.4
2014-01-01     9.2
2015-01-01     9.6
Name: Death rate, crude (per 1,000 people), dtype: float64
```

I use the following code to generate different (p, d, q) values then try each value and get the corresponding AIC, then choose the one that is related to the least AIC. Then use this (p, d, q) values in prediction.

```
import datetime
import warnings
import itertools
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as mse

def MAPE (A, F):
    import numpy as np
    n = len(A)
    Av = np.array(A.values)
    Fv = np.array(F.values)
    mape = np.mean(np.abs((Av-Fv)/Av))*100
    mape = np.around(mape, decimals= 2)
    return mape

# Generate pdq combinations
p= d= q= range(7)
pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))

# Choose min pdq corresponding to min AIC
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
param_aic = {}
for param in pdq:
    try:
        mod = sm.tsa.ARIMA(cmortS, order= param)
        result = mod.fit()
        param_aic[param] = result.aic
    except:
        continue

min_aic = min(param_aic.values())
min_param = ()
for pm, aic in param_aic.items():
    if aic == min_aic:
        min_param = pm

# Run the model with min pdq
model = sm.tsa.ARIMA(cmortS, order= min_param)
results = model.fit()

#Forecast validation
tp = ''
if min_param[1] > 0:
    tp = 'levels'
else:
    tp = 'linear'

train_sz = int(len(cmortS)*0.66)
train = cmortS[:train_sz]
tst = cmortS[train_sz:]
pred_strt = tst.index[0]
tst_pred = results.predict(start= pred_strt, typ= tp)
mserror = mse(tst, tst_pred)
mserror = np.round(mserror, decimals= 5)
mp = MAPE(tst, tst_pred)
print('Model order: {}, MAPE: {}%, mse: {}'.format(min_param, mp, mserror)) 

# Prediction
end_yr = '2050'
end_dt = pd.to_datetime(end_yr, format= '%Y')
strt_dt = pd.to_datetime('2014', format= '%Y')
Var_pred = results.predict(start= strt_dt, end= end_dt, typ = tp)

Var_pred
```

and I get the following error when I run it:

```
ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without freq.
```

Although I reindexed the series with a date range with freq= 'AS', I still get the same error.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464182/datetime-issues-while-time-series-predicting-in-pandas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datetime issues while time series predicting in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464182/datetime-issues-while-time-series-predicting-in-pandas)

Comment: I tried the solutions mentioned in this question but still get the same error!

Comment: I was able to run your code just fine after some small adjustments. I couldn't recreate your `ValueError`. I don't know what `typ=tp` is so I removed it. `Model order: (2, 0, 5), MAPE: 3.69%, mse: 0.02115`, `Var_pred` prints out. I recall problems with `freq` in older versions of Statsmodels. I am using version `(0.8.0rc1)`. What version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jarad!

Comment: 'typ' is an argument for the prediction method, it's either 'level' if d>0 or 'linear'  if d=0 [link](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.predict.html) can I know what modifications did you do other than removing 'typ'. I checked my statsmodels version and it's '0.8.0'

Answer (score 0):

Changing the final few lines of your code to this format should resolve the error message:

```
# Prediction
strt_date = pd.to_datetime('2014-01-01 01:00:00')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2050-01-01 01:00:00')
Var_pred = results.predict(start = strt_date, end = end_date, typ = tp) 
Var_pred
```